# $a_n-a_{n-1}+\frac{2}{n}a_{n-2}=0$. Is $\{a_n\}$ eventually positive/negative, or $a_n=O(n^{-2})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

So there is a recusive sequence $\{a_n\}$ with

\begin{equation}a_n-a_{n-1}+\frac{2}{n}a_{n-2}=0, \quad (n\geq 2)\tag1 \end{equation}

values of $a_0$ and $a_1$ being arbitrary. Is it true that:

> Conjecture 1. $\{a_n\}$ is eventually positive or eventually negative, or
>
> Conjecture 2. $\{a_n\}=O(n^{-2}\,)$?

### Notes

Conjecture 1 implies Conjecture 2 since if $\{a_n\}$ is eventually of the same sign, then $b_n:=n(n-1)a_n$ satisfies
$$b_{n}=b_{n-1}-4a_{n-3}$$
and hence $\{b_n\}$ is bounded, so $a_n=O(n^{-2}\,)$ follows.

So the problem boils down to:

- Prove/Disprove Conjecture 1, or
- Prove/Disprove Conjecture 2 in a separated way.

Supporting Conjecture 1 are the first 21 terms of the sequence with $a_0=0, a_1=1$:
\begin{multline*}0,1, 1,{{1}\over{3}},
-{{1}\over{6}},
-{{3}\over{10}},
-{{11}\over{45}},
-{{10}\over{63}},
-{{41}\over{420}},
-{{101}\over{1620}},
-{{607}\over{14175}},
-{{1091}\over{34650}},\\
-{{2278}\over{93555}},
-{{10783}\over{552825}},
-{{227407}\over{14189175}},
-{{659441}\over{49116375}},
-{{8335507}\over{729729000}},\\
-{{56984107}\over{5789183400}},
-{{837616139}\over{97692469875}},
-{{3292116007}\over{436742806500}},
-{{27555605257}\over{4124793172500}}\end{multline*}
and $a_0=1,a_1=0$: 
\begin{multline*}1,
0,
-1,
-1,
-{{1}\over{2}},
-{{1}\over{10}},
{{1}\over{15}},
{{2}\over{21}},
{{11}\over{140}},
{{31}\over{540}},
{{197}\over{4725}},
{{361}\over{11550}},
{{758}\over{31185}},\\
{{3593}\over{184275}},
{{75797}\over{4729725}},
{{219811}\over{16372125}},
{{2778497}\over{243243000}},
{{18994697}\over{1929727800}},\\
{{279205369}\over{32564156625}},
{{1097371997}\over{145580935500}},
{{9185201747}\over{1374931057500}}\end{multline*}

Finally, I also want to know where to find more material on non-autonomous recurrence relations like $(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some computations a couple of years ago:

---

> **Claim.** Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $a_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfies the recurrence relation
>   $$ a_{n} = a_{n-1} + \frac{a}{n} a_{n-2}, \quad n \geq 2. $$
>   Then $(a_n)$ satisfies the bound $ a_{n} = \mathcal{O}\left( n^{a} \right) $.

*Proof.* Let $A_{n}$ and $B_{n}$ be sequences of $2\times 2$ matrices defined by

\begin{align*}
A_{n} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \tfrac{a}{n} \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
B_{n} = \begin{pmatrix} -\tfrac{a}{n} & 1+\tfrac{a}{n} \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Note that $A_n$ are designed to realize the recurrence relation of $(a_n)$, which means that the following identity holds.

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} a_{n} \\ a_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} = A_{n} \cdots A_{2} \begin{pmatrix} a_{1} \\ a_{0} \end{pmatrix}, \quad n \geq 2.
\end{align*}

Now we introduce $\tilde{A}_{n} = B_{n+1}^{-1} A_{n} B_{n}$. After some tedious calculation, we check that

\begin{align*}
\tilde{A}_{n}
&= \frac{1}{n (n+2a+1)} \begin{pmatrix} -a n - a(a+1) & (a-1) a \\ -a^{2} & n^{2} + (3a+1) n + (a^{2} + 2 a) \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} -\tfrac{a}{n} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 + \tfrac{a}{n} \end{pmatrix} + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{2}} \right).
\end{align*}

Thus for sufficiently large $n$, the operator norm $\| \tilde{A}_{n} \|$ of $\tilde{A}_{n}$ satisfies the following bound

\begin{align*}
\| \tilde{A}_{n} \|
\leq 1 + \frac{a}{n} + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{2}} \right).
\end{align*}

Applying this to $A_{n} \cdots A_{2}$, we have

\begin{align*}
\| A_{n} \cdots A_{2} \|
&= \| B_{n+1} \tilde{A}_{n} \cdots \tilde{A}_{2} B_{2} \|
\lesssim \exp \left\{ \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{a}{k} + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{k^{2}} \right) \right\}
\lesssim n^{a}.
\end{align*}

This proves our bound as desired. ////

Intuitions behind the proof are as follows:

1. Write the recurrence equation as $a_{n} - a_{n-1} = (a/n)a_{n-2}$. Heuristically, its continuous analogue is $y' = (a/x) y$. Then it is easy to check that the solution is of the form $y = c x^{a}$. So we can expect a similar asymptotic behavior for $a_{n}$.
2. The column vectors of $B_{n}$ are very close (up to $\mathcal{O}(n^{-2})$) to eigenvectors of $A_{n}$. Thus $\tilde{A}_{n}$ is essentially the matrix representation of $A_{n}$ with respect to eigenvectors of $A_{n}$ and $A_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll demonstrate that

\begin{equation} \tag{1}
 a_{n+1}=-\alpha \frac{2^{n}(n-1)}{(n+1)!} + f(\beta,n+1)
\end{equation}

with $a_0=\alpha$ and $a_1=\alpha+\beta$, for some $f$. I'll doing so because, at the end of the demonstration, we get a simpler problem to be solved (when $a_0=\alpha=0$ and $a_1=\beta$).

Suppose $(1)$ holds for $n$ and $n-1$. We want to show that holds for $n+1$. Then:
$$a_{n+1}=a_{n}-\frac{2}{n+1}a_{n-1}=-\alpha \frac{2^{n-1}(n-2)}{n!}+f(\beta,n)-\frac{2}{n+1}\left( -\alpha\frac{2^{n-2}(n-3)}{(n-1)!} +f(\beta,n-1) \right) = $$

$$= -\alpha \frac{2^{n-1}(n-2)}{n!}+\frac{2}{n+1}\alpha\frac{2^{n-2}(n-3)}{(n-1)!} -\frac{2}{n+1}f(\beta,n-1) +f(\beta,n) = $$

$$= -\alpha \frac{2^{n-1}(n-2)(n+1)}{n!(n+1)}
+\alpha\frac{2^{n-1}n(n-3)}{(n+1)n!} 
-\frac{2}{n+1}f(\beta,n-1) +f(\beta,n) = $$

$$= -\alpha \frac{2^{n-1}}{(n+1)!} \left( (n-2)(n+1)-n(n-3) \right) -\frac{2}{n+1}f(\beta,n-1) +f(\beta,n) = $$

$$= -\alpha \frac{2^{n-1}}{(n+1)!} \left( 2n-2 \right) -\frac{2}{n+1}f(\beta,n-1) +f(\beta,n) = $$
Finally for some unknow $f$:
$$=-\alpha \frac{2^{n}(n-1)}{(n+1)!} +f(\beta,n+1)$$

Now we check that $(1)$ holds for the first step of the sequence:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
n& a_n    \\ \hline
0& \alpha \\ \hline
1& \alpha + \beta \\ \hline
2& \beta       \\ \hline
3& -\frac{2}{3}\alpha + \frac{1}{3}\beta       \\ \hline
4& -\frac{2}{3}\alpha - \frac{1}{6}\beta         \\ \hline
5& -\frac{2}{5}\alpha - \frac{3}{10}\beta         \\ \hline
\end{array}

It's easy to check that the coefficients of $\alpha$ at the step $n$ are $\frac{2^n(n-1)}{(n+1)!}$
So by induction, (1) holds for every $n$

But the list line of the demonstration imposes an aditional constraint to $f$:
$$f(\beta,n+1) = f(\beta,n)-\frac{2}{n}f(\beta,n-1)$$
that can be rewritten as:
$$b_{n} = b_{n-1} - \frac{2}{n}b_{n-2}$$
With $b_0=0$ and $b_1=\beta$.

Comment: It's easy to check that $f(\beta,n)=\beta g(n)$ for some $g$. So the coefficient of $\beta$ at the $n$-th step is linear to $\beta$ (as it was for $\alpha$). So we just want to find a single case of $\beta$ to solve the entire problem. For example $b_0=0$ and $b_1=1$

Comment: An alternative way I had tried to reach your conclusion is through generating function. Letting $A(t):=\sum a_n t^n$ we get $(1-t)A'(t)+(2t-1)A(t)=\beta$, which gives $A(t)=\alpha(1-t)e^{2t}$ when $\beta=0$, and expands to your first term. Apparently the solution for $\alpha=0,\beta\ne 0$ expands to your second term.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an alternative way to prove $a_n=O(n^{-2}~)$ using generating functions.

Letting $A(t)=\sum a_n t^n$ we get an Initial Value Problem
\begin{equation}\begin{cases}(1-t)A'(t)+(2t-1)A(t)=a_1-a_0 \\A(0)=a_0\end{cases} \tag1\end{equation} 
and it solves to
$$A(t)=a_0(1-t)e^{2t}+(a_1-a_0)(1-t)e^{2t}\int_{0}^{t} \frac{e^{-2s}}{(1-s)^2}ds$$
After integration by parts and some rearrangement, it can be written that
\begin{equation}A(t)=F(t)+2(a_1-a_0)(1-t)e^{2t-2}\int_0^t\frac{ds}{1-s}\end{equation}
where
$$F(t)=a_1-a_0-(a_1-2a_0)(1-t)e^{2t}+2(a_1-a_0)(1-t)e^{2t}\int_0^t\frac{e^{-2s}-e^{-2}}{1-s}ds$$
is an entire function.

So
\begin{equation}A(t)=F(t)+c(1-t)e^{2t}\log(1-t) \tag2\end{equation}
with some entire function $F$ and constant $c$.

The entireness of $F$ implies that its Taylor coefficients tend to $0$ more rapidly than any geometric sequence, and of course, it is $O(n^{-2}~)$. We only need to show if
$$(1-t)e^{2t}\log(1-t)=\sum\eta_n t^n$$
then $\eta_n=O(n^{-2}~)$. Denote
$$(1-t)\log(1-t)=\sum \beta_n t^n,\quad e^{2t}=\sum \gamma_n t^n$$
It is easy to know
$$|\beta_n|\leq Kn^{-2},\quad |\gamma_n|\leq Le^{-2n} \quad(\forall n\geq 1)$$
For some positive constant $K$ and $L$. So
\begin{eqnarray}|\eta_n| =\left|\sum_{j=0}^n\beta_{n-j}~\gamma_{j}\right|&\leq& \sum_{j=0}^{h(n)}|\beta_{n-j}~\gamma_{j}|+ \sum_{j=h(n)+1}^{n} |\beta_{n-j}~\gamma_{j}|\\
& \leq  & K(n-h(n))^{-2}~\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|\gamma_j|+K_0\sum_{j=h(n)+1}^{\infty}|\gamma_j|\\
&\leq  & K_1(n-h(n))^{-2}+K_2 e^{-2(h(n)+1)}\end{eqnarray}
for positive constants $K_0,K_1,K_2$ and positive integer $h(n)$. Now let $h(n):= [\log n]$ We get
$$|\eta_n|\leq K_1(n-\log n)^{-2} +K_2 e^{-2\log n}\leq M n^{-2}$$
for large $n$, as desired.